# .NET to .NetCore/.netstandard

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am upgrading my application from .Net to .Netstandard(Which is Core compliant)

Now, I came across a lot of articles but none of them specifically answers my questions. I have following questions:

1. Most of the articles refer to Project.json. Well, we are VS2017 .NEtStandard1.6 and Microssoft has already got rid of that file. Is there a good article on handling this migration?
2. This is a console application, should I create a new solution and copy each file one by one or is there a short-cut to -re-tatget my framework from .NET 4.6 to .netstandard1.6
3. if re-targetting in the same solution works then I am not seeing netstandard1.6 as a target option to upgrade

What is the best way to address this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new csproj format works with all files in the folder by default. Your best course of action is to create a new .net core console application project and any files you put in its directory will become part of the project.

You state that this is a console application, but talk about targeting .Net Standard.  For the application itself, you need to target a framework (.Net 4.6, .Net Core, Mono), not a standard. Any libraries you have, can target a .Net standard level, but the executables should be targeting frameworks.

Comment: regarding your comment that my project should not be .netstandard intead of that it should be CORE or 4.6. My concern is that I am consuming a third party .Nuget which is based on `netstandard` would that work?

Comment: As long as the framework you are targeting supports that standard, you should be fine. The standard defines what APIs will be available, the framework provides the implementation of those APIs.